# Validation in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, enterprise-library

In my ASP.net application, I am referring the following dll file for validation in my business object class file..

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators;
```

and I am validating the properties like this

```
[StringLengthValidator(1, 50, MessageTemplateResourceName = "INVALID_NAME", 
 MessageTemplateResourceType = typeof(ValidatioinErrors))]
[RegexValidator("[A-Za-z]*", MessageTemplateResourceName = "INVALID_NAME",
 MessageTemplateResourceType = typeof(ValidatioinErrors))]
public string Name
{
  get { return name; }
  set { name = value; }
}
```

Now I am passing the value for Name as "test123", when I check this validation by using the IsValid() function like

```
public bool IsValid()
{
   return Validation.Validate<myclassname>(this).IsValid;
}
```

And when I check this IsValid() function after passing the value for name as "test123", it accepts this given name instead of returning invalid name by rejecting it.

where am I committing mistake? can anyone help me here....

Comment: Try it with a regex of `^[A-Za-z]*$`. The added '^' and '$' mean that that regex should match the entire string instead of just a part of it. The asp.net regexvalidator doesn't need this but this attribute might.

Comment: thanks alot Hans Kesting, its working fine..........

Comment: @Hans Kesting:can u post this in answer session, so that I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a regex of `^[A-Za-z]*$`.

The added '^' and '$' mean that that regex should match the entire string instead of just a part of it.

The asp.net regexvalidator doesn't need these but that's an exception. Regular regexes need these anchors to match only the full input, and this attribute apparently does also.